# Scalar triple product and the Determinate

Tags: math

I noticed something when I was trying to solve a problem today.  The scalar triple product  is the same as the determinant or a three by three matrix with three vectors as rows:

A = [**a**, **b**, **c**]

det(A) = (**a** X **b**) * **c**

I came across this in *Real Timer Rendering*, and I can't really figure out why this is, or if its even useful.  It seems sort of related to the short cut method of computing the cross product using a determinate where you write the unit vectors along the top of the matrix, but I always thought that was more of a mnemonic and not actually sound math.

Is there a real relationship here, or is this just some kind of happy coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to a sign, the determinant of an n-by-n matrix is the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by its n n-dimensional row (or column) vectors (or the volume of a unit cube 
linearly transformed by that matrix).  The (axb).c product does, in three dimensions,  exactly the same; axb gives a vector perpendicular to a and b and of length equal to the area of the parallelogram spanned by a and b; (axb).c gives the height of c over that parallelogram, times its area. So, no, it's no coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

No coincidence at all; this is a fairly standard result.  Note that cross products a X b are often written in determinant form themselves with the top row being the unit vectors i j k, the next row being a1 a2 a3 and the bottom row being b1 b2 b3.

```
|i  j   k|
|a1 a2 a3|
|b1 b2 b3|
```

Now taking the dotproduct of that with another vector c, and you get the same thing as if you had just written c in the top row.

```
|i  j   k|                      |c1 c2 c3|     |c1 c2 c3|    |a1 a2 a3|
|a1 a2 a3| .  (c1,c2,c3)  =     |a1 a2 a3|  = -|a1 a2 a3|  = |b1 b2 b3|
|b1 b2 b3|                      |b1 b2 b3|     |b1 b2 b3|    |c1 c2 c3|
```

Edit: Also the [wikipedia page for scalar triple product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) says that its equivalent to the determinant of the matrix using the vectors as rows or columns.  Q.E.D.

Comment: I noticed that, but I always thought it wasn't OK to mix vector values and scalar values in a Matrix.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that it's strictly proper, but its written that way in every linear algebra textbook that I've ever seen.  Really this is just syntactic sugar.  We could also show it by expanding everything, but that'd be a bit of a mess.

Comment: And even if you can, it doesn't really explain the link - I've never seen a proof using the determinate form of the cross product the proofs I've seen always start from the definitions of i, j, and k in relation to each other.

Comment: Yeah, I've always seen it too, but after a proof that doesn't use that form.  It's always oh yeah, and you can do this to remember it.